# SQL- retrieving distinct ID

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with the following data:

```
ID   NAME    ATTRIBUTE   CODE
=============================
1     XX         MM        GC
1     XX         ST        GC
2     ZZ         LL        GC
2     ZZ         ST        GC
3     AA         MM        PC
```

I need the `ID`, name of from the table which contains either `MM` Attribute or `GC` code but not both. Like the query should retrieve the `ID` numbers only 2 and 3  but not 1 .

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Id, Name

From #t
Where (Attribute = 'MM' Or Code = 'GC')
And Id Not In (Select Id From #t 
                Where (Attribute = 'MM' And Code = 'GC'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct T1.ID,
                T1.NAME
from T as T1
where (T1.ATTRIBUTE = 'MM' or T1.CODE = 'GC') and
      not exists (select *
                  from T as T2
                  where T1.ID = T2.ID and
                        T2.Attribute = 'MM' and
                        T2.CODE = 'GC')
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME
2   ZZ
3   AA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct ID
from TableName
where (Attribute = 'MM' or Code = 'GC')
  and not (Attribute = 'MM' AND Code = 'GC')
```

Comment: Won't this return a 1, due to the second row of data?

Comment: @AakashM: Yep, I think you are right. I did not notice that. I think @Barry's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME
  FROM <YOUR-TABLE-NAME>
 WHERE 
 (ATTRIBUTE = 'MM' AND CODE <> 'GC') OR
 (ATTRIBUTE <> 'MM' AND CODE = 'GC') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct Id, Name
from tbl?
where 
(attribute = 'MM' or code = 'GC')
and not (attribute = 'MM' and code = 'GC')

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    SELECT ID, NAME FROM TableName WHERE CODE = 'GC'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ID, NAME FROM TableName WHERE ATTRIBUTE = 'MM'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT ID, NAME FROM TableName WHERE ATTRIBUTE = 'MM'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ID, NAME FROM TableName WHERE CODE = 'GC'
)
```